# Leaflet for R: Is there a way to add an outline to minicharts pie charts and barplots?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I'm using leaflet in R to visualize pie charts and bar plots on a map. I am using the following code to create the maps (example shown for pie charts):

```
data = data.frame(site = c("site1", "site2"), lat = c(42.6076, 43.7452), 
                  lon = c(-101.5471, -99.7837), factor1 = c(10,40), 
                  factor2 = c(50, 60))

leaflet() %>% 
addTiles() %>% 
addMinicharts(data$lon, data$lat, type = "pie", colorPalette = c("blue", "red"), 
width = 50, chartdata = data[,c(4:ncol(data))])
```

Is there a way to add a border/outline to the pie/slices in R leaflect minicharts? In reality I have many more factors to depict in each pie chart, so including an outline will help the slices stand out a little more (and also help the whole pie stand out against the map). I haven't found any indication that this capability exists, but thought I'd ask the community here in case it does. Thanks!